# Attributes from style files having no effects on views

Tags: java, android, layout, styles, view

I am using some style files in my Android application, I have for example:

```
<style name="message">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>
```

And then I create some components using these styles by doing:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.message));
```

My problem is that I noticed some attributes having no effect on my components, in this case, *layout_weight* is not working and I am obliged to specify it in my code as below:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.weight = 1;
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you have an idea, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: I've come across some opinions that this method of programmatic styling ignores certain attributes. Thus, chances are, there's no way to avoid setting layout params separately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies on the fact that `android:layout_weight` works only with certain `LayoutParam`s as you've experienced.

As a general best practice in regards with styles on Android, it is advisable not to include `layout` specific attributes into your styles, as your styled view can be reused and sit in different layouts.

Comment: So I need to set the layout attributes always in my code for the components I add to my layouts with code?
Because when the components/views are added directly from the xml layout files, there is no problem, the problem only occurs when I generate components from my code.

Comment: Being dependent on the LayoutParams, yes. Different LayoutParams have different attributes you can set.